# Debian Wheezy hangs before GRUB menu after successful install on Dell C-Series Server

Tags: debian, debian-wheezy, grub2

I've just installed Debian Wheezy on a Dell C-Series Server w/o any problems. However, at first reboot, I don't even get a GRUB menu. So I guess it's a problem with where GRUB was installed and maybe the RAID configuration.

The server has 6 HD's, 2 being system disks configured as RAID 1, 4 SSD's for data configured as RAID 0. The first two were recognized as `/dev/sdc`, the additional four as `/dev/sdb` and the USB boot stick from which I installed Debian as `/dev/sda`.

During installation Debian was suggesting to install GRUB to the MBR of `/dev/sdc`. The entries in `/etc/fstab` use UUID's so the problem can't be non persistent device names over reboot. I've tried to manually re-install GRUB using `grub-install /dev/sdc` as well as `grub-install '(hd2)'` which, according to `/boot/grub/device.map`, is GRUB's way of saying `/dev/sdc`. Both returned No error occurred.

However, I still can't reboot the server. I'm feel like I'm making a stupid rookie mistake. Any advice?

For the sake of completeness I'M using Debian Wheezy 7.4.